# mousemove event not working like expected in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, mousemove

I have some code below for the start of a snake game that I'm making using HTML5 canvas. For some reason, the red circle that I'm temporarily using to represent my snake is drawing constantly following the path the mouse moves in. and it uses the food as a starting point. Check it out in your browser, because it's really hard to describe. All I want is for the circle to follow the mouse and leave a small trail that ends and doesn't stay on the canvas. How would I go about doing this. Thanks in advance!

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Snake 2.0</title>
</head>

<style>

</style>

<body>
    <div>
        <canvas id="canvas" width=500 height=500></canvas>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

    makeFood();

    function makeFood() {
        foods = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++){
            foods.push(new Food());
        }
    }

    function Food() {
        this.x = Math.random() * canvas.width;
        this.y = Math.random() * canvas.height;
        this.radius = 10;

    }

    function drawFood() {
        for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++){
            foods.push(new Food());
        }


        for (var i = 0; i < foods.length; i++){     
            var f = foods[i];
            context.beginPath();

            var grd = context.createRadialGradient(f.x, f.y, (f.radius - (f.radius - 1)), f.x + 1, f.y + 1, (f.radius));
            grd.addColorStop(0, 'red');
            grd.addColorStop(1, 'blue');
            context.arc(f.x, f.y, f.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
            context.fillStyle = grd;
            context.fill();

        }
    }

    function makePower() {
        powers = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++){
            powers.push(new Power());
        }
    }   

    function Power() {
        this.x = Math.random() * canvas.width;
        this.y = Math.random() * canvas.height;
        this.radius = 8;

    }

    function drawPower() {


        for (var i = 0; i < powers.length; i++){        
            var p = powers[i];
            context.beginPath();

            var grd = context.createRadialGradient(p.x, p.y, (p.radius - (p.radius - 1)), p.x + 1, p.y + 1, (p.radius));
            grd.addColorStop(0, 'green');
            grd.addColorStop(1, 'yellow');
            context.arc(p.x, p.y, p.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
            context.fillStyle = grd;
            context.fill();


        }
    }

    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event) {
        move(event);
        }); 

    function move(e) {
        context.fillStyle = "black";
        context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);    

        var a = e.clientX;
        var b = e.clientY;
        context.arc(a, b, 20, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
        context.fillStyle = "red";
        context.fill();
    }



    context.fillStyle = "black";
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);    
    var functions = [drawFood];


    var timer = setInterval(function(){
                drawFood();
            }, 5000);


    function stop() {
        clearInterval(timer);
    }


    canvas.addEventListener("click", stop);
    //timer = setInterval(start, 1000);
    //timer = setInterval(start, 5000);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sd5hh57b/) of OP's code.

Comment: Awesome, thank you for that!

Answer (score 0):

You could start by adding "context.beginPath();" in your "move" function, before "context.arc(a, b, 20, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);", line 102-103 in my editor.

```
function move(e) {
    context.fillStyle = "black";
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    var a = e.clientX;
    var b = e.clientY;
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(a, b, 20, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
    context.fillStyle = "red";
    context.fill();
}
```

Here is the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/sd5hh57b/1/

Answer (score 0):

You should store the positions you move along in an array. Then a new timer should revisit those discs and redraw them in a more faded color each time it ticks, until a disc becomes black. Then it should be removed from that array.

Here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d20xajjm/) that does that.

The change in the code starts at `canvas.addEventListener("mousemove",...` and goes like this:

```
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event) {
    // Replaced move function by drawDisc function, 
    // which needs coordinates and color intensity
    drawDisc(event.clientX, event.clientY, 0xF);
}); 

// Array to keep track of previous positions, i.e. the trail
var trail = [];

function drawDisc(x, y, red) {
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(x, y, 20, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
    context.fillStyle = '#' + red.toString(16) + '00000';
    context.fill();
    // If disc is not completely faded out, push it in the trail list
    if (red) {
        trail.push({x: x, y: y, red: red});
    }
}

// New function to regularly redraw the trail
function fadeTrail() {
    var discs = trail.length;
    // If there is only one disc in the trail, leave it as-is, 
    // it represents the current position.
    if (discs > 1) {
        for (var i = discs; i; i--) {
           // take "oldest" disc out of the array:
           disc = trail.shift();
           // and draw it with a more faded color, unless it is
           // the current disc, which keeps its color
           drawDisc(disc.x, disc.y, disc.red - (i === 1 ? 0 : 1));
        }
    }
}
// New timer to fade the trail
var timerFade = setInterval(function(){
    fadeTrail();
}, 10);
```

I think the comments will make clear what this does. Note that the colors of the discs go from 0xF00000 to 0xE00000, 0xD00000, ... , 0x000000. Except the current disc, that one keeps its 0xF00000 color all the time.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are right :

- Use [`beginPath()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/beginPath) at each new `arc()` to create a new Path and avoid `context.fill()` considers the whole as a single Path.
- Use a trail Array to store your last positions to draw the trail.

But, the use of `setTimeout` and `setInterval` should be avoided (and even further the use of multiple ones).
Modern browsers do support [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame) timing method, and for olders (basically IE9), you can find [polyfills](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/1579671) quite easily. It has a lot of advantages that I won't enumerate here, read the docs.

Here is a modified version of your code, which uses a `requestAnimationFrame` loop.
I also created two offscreen canvases to update your `foods` and `powers`, this way they won't disappear at each draw. Both will be painted in the draw function.

I changed the mousemove handler so it only updates the trail array, leaving the drawing part in the draw loop. At each call, it will set a `moving` flag that will let our draw function know that we are moving the mouse. Otherwise, it will start to remove old trail arcs from the Array.

```js
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
     // create other contexts (layer like) for your food and powers
    var foodContext = canvas.cloneNode(true).getContext('2d');
    var pwrContext = canvas.cloneNode(true).getContext('2d');

     // a global to tell weither we are moving or not
    var moving;
     // a global to store our animation requests and to allow us to pause it
    var raf;

     // an array to store our trail position
    var trail = [];
     // here we can determine how much of the last position we'll keep at max (can then be updated if we ate some food)
    var trailLength = 10;

     // your array for the foods
    var foods = [];
     // a global to store the last time we drawn the food, no more setInterval
    var lastDrawnFood = 0;


     // start the game
    draw();

    function makeFood() {
      foods.push(new Food());
    }

    function Food() {
      this.x = Math.random() * canvas.width;
      this.y = Math.random() * canvas.height;
      this.radius = 10;

    }

    function drawFood() {
        // clear the food Canvas (this could be done only if we ate some, avoiding the loop through all our foods at each call of this method)
        foodContext.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        foods.push(new Food());
        for (var i = 0; i < foods.length; i++) {
          var f = foods[i];
          // draw on the food context
          foodContext.beginPath();
          foodContext.arc(f.x, f.y, f.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
          var foodGrd = foodContext.createRadialGradient(f.x, f.y, (f.radius - (f.radius - 1)), f.x + 1, f.y + 1, (f.radius));
          foodGrd.addColorStop(0, 'red');
          foodGrd.addColorStop(1, 'blue');
          foodContext.fillStyle = foodGrd;
          foodContext.fill();

        }
      }
      // I'll let you update this one

    function makePower() {
      powers = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        powers.push(new Power());
      }
    }

    function Power() {
      this.x = Math.random() * canvas.width;
      this.y = Math.random() * canvas.height;
      this.radius = 8;

    }

    function drawPower() {
        pwrContext.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        for (var i = 0; i < powers.length; i++) {
          var p = powers[i];
          var pwrGrd = pwrContext.createRadialGradient(p.x, p.y, (p.radius - (p.radius - 1)), p.x + 1, p.y + 1, (p.radius));
          pwrGrd.addColorStop(0, 'green');
          pwrGrd.addColorStop(1, 'yellow');
          pwrContext.beginPath();

          pwrContext.arc(p.x, p.y, p.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
          pwrContext.fillStyle = pwrGrd;
          pwrContext.fill();


        }
      }
      // the event object is already passed, no need for an anonymous function here
    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", move);

    function move(e) {
      // we paused the game, don't update our position
      if (!raf) return;
      // update the snake
      var a = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
      var b = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
      trail.splice(0, 0, {
        x: a,
        y: b
      });
      // tell our draw function that we moved
      moving = true;
    }


    function draw(time) {
      // our food timer
      if (time - lastDrawnFood > 5000) {
        lastDrawnFood = time;
        drawFood();
      }

      // clear the canvas
      context.fillStyle = "black";
      context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      // draw the food
      context.drawImage(foodContext.canvas, 0, 0);
      // draw the power
      context.drawImage(pwrContext.canvas, 0, 0);
      //draw the snake
      for (var i = 0; i < trail.length; i++) {
        // decrease the opacity
        opacity = 1 - (i / trail.length);
        context.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 0,0," + opacity + ")";
        // don't forget to create a new Path for each circle
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(trail[i].x, trail[i].y, 20, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
        context.fill();
      }
      // if we're not moving or if our trail is too long
      if ((!moving || trail.length > trailLength) && trail.length > 1)
      // remove the oldest trail circle
        trail.pop();

      // we're not moving anymore
      moving = false;
      // update the animation request
      raf = requestAnimationFrame(draw);
    }

    context.fillStyle = "black";
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    function toggleStop() {
      if (!raf) {
        // restart the animation
        raf = window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
      } else {
        // cancel the next call
        cancelAnimationFrame(raf);
        raf = 0;
      }
    }


    canvas.addEventListener("click", toggleStop);
```

```css
html, body{margin:0;}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=500 height=500></canvas>
```